# Let $G$ be any group with $|G| =N=123456789$. Let $g\in G$, and $M=2^{2^{2524820221019}}$. Then $g$ satisfies $g^M = e$ if and only if $g = e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

> Let $G$ be any group with $|G| = N = 123456789$. Let $g$ be any element of $G$, and $M = 2^{2^{2524820221019}}\ \ \ \ \ $. Then $g$ satisfies $g^M = e$ if and only if $g = e$.

I am trying to determine if this is true. I think information like $M$ is even and $N$ is odd is useful. I think it is false since $N$ cannot divide $M$ but other than that I don't really understand what is going on.

Comment: Hint: Do you know what the possible orders of elements of $G$ are?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut would the order of $G$ be $123456789$ in this case?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut The other thing that comes to mind is that $M$ in this case is not the smallest possible integer to be the order of $g$ therefore the order is infinite and $e = g^M$ is true.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem tells you something about the order of every element of $G$, and just staring at the order of $G$ tells you something about it as it relates to the prime $2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So since the order of $G$ is odd and not divisible by 2 then that means $g^M = e$ cannot be true unless $g = e$?

Comment: Are you asking me or telling me? If you are asking, you are just repeating the question and adding what I told you as a preamble, so I will simply repeat the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

One direction is trivial.

In general,  $g^k=e\implies \lvert g\rvert \mid k$.

So $g^M=e\implies \lvert g\rvert \mid M\implies \lvert g\rvert =2^l$ for some $l$.

But since $\lvert N\rvert $ is odd, and by Lagrange $\lvert g\rvert \mid N$, we have $g=e$.

Answer (score 2):

Since M only has factors of 2, the only factor of M that is odd is 1. Therefore $g^M$ = e implies $g^1$ = e implies g = e.

Comment: How do we know $M = 1$ does its only odd factor of 1 mean that it will be reduced to one in the group $G$?

Comment: @Anonymous98737943 The order of $g$ divides both $M$ and the order of $G$, so it divides their gcd. The order of $G$ is odd, so the gcd is odd. Since the only odd number that divides $M$ is $1$...